# How to manually implement autochdir?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

```
'autochdir' 'acd'   boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {only available when compiled with it, use
            exists("+autochdir") to check}
    When on, Vim will change the current working directory whenever you
    open a file, switch buffers, delete a buffer or open/close a window.
    It will change to the directory containing the file which was opened
    or selected.
    This option is provided for backward compatibility with the Vim
    released with Sun ONE Studio 4 Enterprise Edition.
    Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work.
```

What are all of the hooks that you'd have to listen to to simulate autochdir?

I guess at least one would look like this

```
autocmd BufEnter * :cd expand('%:p:h')
```

How can all of the functionality of `autochdir` be implemented?

Comment: From a cursory look at the code, "hooks" and "listening" are not involved. The macro is called explicitly (search for `do_autochdir`).